# How do I disable asking password when doing git push/pull to vps server?

Tags: git, automation

Is there any way to set server password with local git repository? when every time i push to serve it's ask me to provide password. i want to make it's automatic with one time config.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your URL (`git remote -v` inside your local repository to show it)

- HTTPS means you need to activate a [credential caching setting](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Credential-Storage)
- SSH means it asks you for the passphrase which does protect the private key (you need to [cache it with an SSH agent](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent#adding-your-ssh-key-to-the-ssh-agent))
  Or: you did not add the public key to the server account `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file, and SSH falls back to that server account password.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your `.git/config` file.
The remote part will look like this:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://url.tld
```

Change it to

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@url:/path/on/server
```

Then it will use SSH.
You can copy your SSH Key to the server and never will be asked for a password again

Comment: at config file my url look like this  url = ssh://root@74.208.23.154/var/repo/site.git

Answer (score 0):

git provides storage of the credential

```
$ git config credential.helper store
$ git push http://example.com/repo.git
Username: <type your username>
Password: <type your password>

[several days later]
$ git push http://example.com/repo.git
[your credentials are used automatically]
```

it basically does is store the credential in .git-credentials file
`https://user:pass@example.com`
check these official docs: [git credential store](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-store)
and [Credential Storage](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Credential-Storage)